# I want change background color in javascript without using click button

Tags: javascript

I want change `background color` without using click button

```
<script>  
    onclick.document.getElementById('myDiv').style.backgroundColor = 'red';   
</script>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to the SO community, you should add more description to your problem if you want to be helped. You should describe exactly what is your problem and how did you try to solve it. You can read this post: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @VishnuBhadoriya- seems like issue with click event handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to attach click event and then you can do it , there is nothing like this `onclick.document.getElementById(`

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("myDiv").style.backgroundColor = 'red';
});
```

Comment: Thanks Sir its working.

Comment: sorry i cant understand upvote?

Comment: i think so i can accept answer, i jst started stackoverflow also i'm javascript beginner.

Comment: now i know wat u says :) I did mate.

Comment: @Iffy - if you are beginner then you can go through this course : https://www.w3schools.com/jsreF/default.asp not in much detail

Comment: I completed Web Developer course through Treehouse web but still need to improve coding.